# Interpolating a JSON string removes JSON quotations

Tags: json, ruby

I have the following two lines of code:

```
json_str = _cases.to_json
path += " #{USER} #{PASS} #{json_str}"
```

When I use the debugger, I noticed that `json_str` appears to be formatted as JSON:

```
"[["FMCE","Wiltone","Wiltone","04/10/2018","Marriage + - DOM"]]"
```

However, when I interpolate it into another string, the quotes are removed:

```
"node superuser 123456 [["FMCE","Wiltone","Wiltone","04/10/2018","Marriage + - DOM"]]"
```

Why does string interpolation remove the quotes from JSON string and how can I resolve this?

I did find one solution to the problem, which was manually escaping the string:

```
json_str = _cases.to_json.gsub('"','\"')
path += " #{USER} #{PASS} \"#{json_str}\""
```

So basically I escape the double quotes generated in the to_json call. Then I manually add two escaped quotes around the interpolated variable. This will produce a desired result:

```
node superuser 123456 "[[\"FMCE\",\"Wiltone\",\"Wiltone\",\"04/10/2018\",\"Marriage + - DOM\"]]"
```

Notice how the outer quotes around the collection are not escaped, but the strings inside the collection are escaped. That will enable JavaScript to parse it with JSON.parse.

It is important to note that in this part:

```
json_str = _cases.to_json.gsub('"','\"')
```

it is adding a LITERAL backslash. Not an escape sequence.

But in this part:

```
path += " #{USER} #{PASS} \"#{json_str}\""
```

The \" wrapping the interpolated variable is an escape sequence and NOT a literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the first and last quote marks are part of the string? They do not belong to the JSON format. Your program’s behavior looks correct to me.

(Or more precisely, your program seems to be doing exactly what you told it to. Whether your instructions are any good is a question I can’t answer without more context.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with the small sample, but it looks like you might be getting quotes from your debugger output. assuming the output of `.to_json` is a string (usually is), then `"#{json_str}"` should be exactly equal to `json_str`. If it isn't, that's a bug in ruby somehow (doubtful).

If you need the quotes, you need to either add them manually or escape the string using whatever escape function is appropriate for your use case. You could use `.to_json` as your escape function even (`"#{json_str.to_json}"`, for example).